# On BitBucket how do you add an admin to a group?

Tags: permissions, bitbucket

Our company's BitBucket account owner made a new group called admins, gave it admin rights to all repositories (the highest permission he could see), and added me to it.

But when I go to the group page I can't add a new repository, or see the group settings page, like he can.

What else does he need to do to give my account all permissions to the company account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be only one owner of a company account it seems.

So instead create a BitBucket 'team' and then create a 'project' under it. Then transfer all your repositories to that 'project'.

You can give users admin writes to the 'team' to do whatever they want, including creating new repos in the project.